# asp.net and Ajax

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax

I am using the following JavaScript code to refresh another page

```
window.opener.location.replace(url)
```

The problem is when entering the URL, do not find the page as the page is located in the root and this calling code is placed in a page inside another folder. How do I specify the path to point to the root, which is where the page is located? I have tried many things, but none worked:

```
//page.aspx 
../page.aspx 
~/page.aspx
page.aspx
/page.aspx
....
```

Answer (score 0):

This form should work:

```
window.opener.location = url;
```

The replace method replaces a match in the current URL with another string, but it won't work with just one parameter. At any rate, it is not necessary to specify the full URL, you can only specify the partial path such as:

```
../page.htm
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to give exact path